# .Net WCF SVC Info Page and Fully Qualified Server Names

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I have two servers on which the identical .net 2.0 WCF service code has been deployed.  On both servers the code is running in a dedicated web application with a dedicated application pool assigned to it.  Both the web applications and the application pools are configured, as near as I can tell from IIS, identically on both machines.  Furthermore, both machines have the same exact versions of the .net framework installed.

On one server the SVC info page served up by IIS lists a fully qualified machine name but the other lists a non-fully qualified machine name.  I've provided sample URLS to the info page and the results below:

**://server1:1995/Service.svc yields:**

> You have created a service.  To test this service, you will need to
>   create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using
>   the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:
>   **svcutil.exe ://server1.domain.com:1995/Service.svc?wsdl**

**://server2:1995/Service.svc yields:**

> You have created a service.  To test this service, you will need to
>   create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using
>   the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:
>   **svcutil.exe ://server2:1995/Service.svc?wsdl**

I wouldn't normally care about this except for the fact that a packaged product I'm using appears to insist that the URL I give it for the WSDL match exactly what the info page states and I can't figure out why it needs to be different for these two (seemingly identical) machines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(please note I had to delete "http" from the hyperlinks above to keep StackOverflow happy)

Comment: WCF was not around until .NET 3.0....did you mean 3.0, or are referring to the CLR 2.0 (which 3.0/3.5 run on)?

Comment: My bad.  This is a 3.5 WCF service running on the CLR 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here was to add the following line to the SVC web.config file.  The behavior was inconsistent across different versions of IIS (and possibly the .net CLR) but adding this line normalized the behavior:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```